# Unit test spring bean implementation as bean

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot application, using Spring 4, in this app I have an interface and an implementing class:

```
interface Sorter{
   void start();
   List<MailingListMessage> getMessages();
}
```

and

```
@Service
public class SorterImpl implements Sorter {

    List<MailingListMessage> messages;

     @Override
     public void start() {

     }

     @Override
     public List<MailingListMessage> getMessages() {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

What I want to to is test the implementation directly but still as a bean with autowiring and everything.

I want to do that because when I need to assert something that for example relates to messages, I have to make the method public as you can see in the Impl class.

Is there a way in Spring to properly write tests for implementations directly and still have them work as beans?

Thanks.

Comment: See the [Integration testing with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html) section of the official documentation.

Comment: Yes I read through that, it says how to use mocks and test interfaces and things like that, but I am asking about the implementations, testing of implementations

Comment: See [@ContextConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#__contextconfiguration).

Comment: @engma, the _Spring TestContext Framework_ is **not** just about mocks and testing interfaces. It is in fact mostly about testing implementations. I know, because I wrote the framework. ;) So please reread the reference manual and let us know how you progress.